# How to run 3 dependent processes in docker container - Python

Tags: python-3.x, docker, ubuntu, heroku, docker-compose

I have a use case in which I have a StanfordCoreNLPServer listening at /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000, a gensim.py script that initializes a process to serve model and a bottle app (runs on 8080 port) that has a script that takes the input to send it to model, receive output and display on frontend. I am currently running this on my ubuntu OS. But now I need to deploy it to Heroku and before that, I am stuck in creating docker containers and communicating those. Please guide if anyone has handled this use case.

Some further details/commands are as follows:

Stanford Core NLP Server (1st tab):

```
sudo apt install default-jre    #Install Java Runtime Environment
wget http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-corenlp-latest.zip   #download nlp.zip
unzip stanford-corenlp-latest.zip   #Extract core-nlp
cd stanford-corenlp-latest/stanford-corenlp-4.2.0
java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9000 -timeout 15000
```

Install Gensim Server and run the process in another new tab.
File Location: understanding/gensim_server.py

```
pip install "gensim==3.8.1"
pip3 install fuzzywuzzy
python3 gensim_server.py   #initializing process to serve model
```

Open a new tab and run the bottle app.
File Location: understanding/main.py

```
pip3 install bottle
pip3 install nltk
pip3 install python-Levenshtein
python3 main.py #run app on 8080 port
```

Answer (score 0):

Docker docs recommend that you have a separation of concern by running your processes in different containers but they do have have possible [solutions](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/) if you must run them in one container.